# Finding highest value within an n -ary tree

Tags: recursion, tree, binary-tree

I have an arraylist which is linked in a tree structure (a family tree to be precise). Each node is an object containing a generation field. I would like to find the leaf with the highest generation within the tree. I tried this:

```
private int findHighestLeafGeneration(FamilyMember node, int gen){
        if(node.getChildren().isEmpty()){
            return gen;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < node.getChildren().size(); i++){          
            gen = findHighestLeafGeneration(node.getChild(i), node.getChild(i).getGeneration());
        }
        return gen;
    }
```

I call the method like this:

```
findHighestLeafGeneration(node, node.getGeneration());
```

What this is supposed to do is take a member of the family tree (a node) and print all the descendants for that member. My PrintDescendants method requires the number of generations to print.

The above is a little buggy however. It gets the leaf generation then returns and overwrites the leafs generation with the parent nodes generation. Any clues why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

`private int findHighestLeafGeneration(FamilyMember node) {
  int gen = node.getGeneration();
  for(int i = 0; i < node.getChildren().size(); i++){ 
    int highestChild = findHighestLeafGeneration(node.getChild(i));
    if(highestChild > gen) { 
      gen = highestChild;
    }
  }
  return gen;
}`

Comment: Glad you liked it! It is a warning sign when you say "highest" but nowhere in your code you use > or < operators. What if you said "lowest" instead - how would your code change?

Comment: I guess you would change the variable name to lowestChild and swap the > for a <.

Comment: @user559142: Correct, with the solution I proposed. But your original solution does not contain any > or < (except in the loop). That means you do not even have to read the code or run it to know it must be wrong. I find these little logical checks very useful when programming (I know I am doing A. That means that at some point I must do B. Where do I do B? *quick scan* Nowhere? The code is wrong! How to fix it? What about adding B, where should it go? Etc...)